# How to create an "other" group when using GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sqlite

**Summary**: I have data that I group, count, and sort by count. I would like to keep only the first X lines, and have others accumulated as a line called "other"

The data below is [available at DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iRKcDfnhxBZnpsHutFcKxy/0)

```sql
CREATE TABLE cities (name TEXT);
INSERT INTO cities(name) VALUES ('paris'), ('paris'), ( 'london'), ( 'london'), ( 'london'), ( 'london'), ( 'rome'), ( 'madrid');

SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS count FROM cities
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 2
```

The code above generates the top two most present cities (the ones that have the largest number of entries):

```
| name   | count |
| ------ | ----- |
| london | 4     |
| paris  | 2     |
```

What I would like to achieve is

```
| name   | count |
| ------ | ----- |
| london | 4     |
| paris  | 2     |
| other  | 2     |
```

where all remaining rows (`'rome'` and `'madrid'` in my case) are grouped together under `other`.

I do not know SQL very much but in pseudo-code I am thinking about something like

```sql
SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS count FROM cities
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 2 AS top_2
LIMIT 2+ AS other
```

Is this possible in a single pass? As a workaround I will have the same query, but sorted the other way round and limited to "number of rows - the top 2" (so 3 queries in total I think).

*(I am surprised that this has not been asked before, but could not find a match)*

Comment: You want a sum of all others counts or a count of lines at 1 or 2?

Comment: @Elikill58: sorry I do not really understand. I would like the number of all the rows that did not make it in the top 2 to be under others. Here I have one `'rome'` and 1 `'madrid'`, so it is 2. If there were 2 `'rome'` and 1 `'madrid'`, that would be 3. Is this better?

Comment: Oh ok, I see. Yes it's better

Comment: @Elikill58. great. The typical use case is when there are, say, 100 cities, the top 10 make it for 80% of something (say, the population) and then the rest is aggregated in 'other' (so usually descending bars, and one 'other' bar at the end)

Comment: I would take a simple union or union all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use another level of aggregation with a case expression on a row_number function:

```sql
WITH T AS
(
  SELECT
     name, 
     COUNT(name) AS count,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(name) DESC) AS rn 
  FROM cities
  GROUP BY name
  ORDER BY count DESC
)
SELECT 
   CASE 
     WHEN rn IN (1, 2) 
     THEN name 
     ELSE 'Others' 
   END AS name,
   SUM(count) AS count
FROM T
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY count DESC
```

To ensure that 'Other' appear last in the result set, you may `ORDER BY CASE WHEN rn IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, count DESC`

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iRKcDfnhxBZnpsHutFcKxy/1)

Answer (score 0):

With common table expression:

```
WITH
    CTE_All (ct_all) AS
        (SELECT COUNT(name)
        FROM cities),
    CTE_Top (ct_name, ct_count) AS
        (SELECT TOP 2 name, COUNT(name)
        FROM cities
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
        ORDER BY COUNT(name) DESC)

SELECT * FROM CTE_Top
UNION ALL
SELECT 'other', (SELECT ct_all FROM CTE_All) - SUM(ct_count)
    FROM CTE_Top;
```

Comment: SQLite does not support `TOP 2` used in TSQL and Access. No two SQL dialects are alike!